# Chrome extension focus

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a Chrome extension to pop up a "popup" or a "panel" in the front of the currently focused window.  It seems like the focused boolean for chrome.windows.create isn't working.

It **always** opens behind the current window, no matter what I've tried.

```
// popup.html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="loader.js"></script>
</html>

// loader.js
function load() {
  var popupId;

  chrome.windows.create({
    type:   'popup',
    url:    'http://xxx/bookmarks',
    height:  500,
    width:   800,
    focused: true
  }, function(popup) {
    popupId = popup.id;
  });

  chrome.windows.update(popupId, {focused: true});
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onload = function() { load(); };
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing the document.getElementBy... clause to window.onload = function() { load(); };, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't really need the popup page, I would suggest you remove it and instead move your code to open a new window in the javascript file for your background page. You can act on a click on your extension icon by using:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)
```

and supplying your logic in a callback.

Comment: There we go!  It makes a lot of sense to not have that bare html skeleton there, and to use an event page instead.  Thanks a bunch for the tip... that was driving me slightly crazy =)